# Someone said "Ok, talk later" when I said that I wouldn't reply for a while

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

So, what the title says. I'm not a native speaker and, although I have been living in the UK for 2 years, some expressions are still new to me.

Context: I met a girl 4 days ago. We went out on a date and, since then, we talked probably twice through texts (I'm away on a work trip, bad timing). Today, I finished a text by saying "I won't reply for a while, I'm going to a meeting". And she replied "Ok, talk later :)".

Now, is this the typical "See you later" or is this literal, like "Ok, talk to me later in the day"? It sounds quite stupid, but I don't know that person that well and I don't want to make any mistakes.

Comment: In all likelihood, she meant see you later. The ":)" at the end makes it seem more like a sign-off than an attempt to schedule a later conversation. That said, it's always best to directly ask if communication is unclear. It is unlikely to be held against you and usually is appreciated - not to mention it helps avoid misunderstandings and mistakes.

Comment: Ok, talk later means here: Ok, we'll talk later [by texting each other]. OR by phone. It is not see you later.

Answer (score 1):

**It's a shorthand way of saying "Okay, we'll talk later."**

In all likelihood, she wouldn't have phrased it that way if she were speaking to you instead of texting. Because it's more tedious to text/type than it is to speak, she shortened the sentence figuring you would be able to guess the pronoun without her having to type it.

Comment: When speaking, it's totally common to hear (e. g. when finishing phone conversations), "OK, talk to you later". So it can also mean _"I"_ will talk to you later. In any case, this is a way to say that "our conversation will continue at a later time."